# How to delete an Approval Process

Tags: approval-process

how can we delete an apporval process. I have an apporval process on a object and, I can see only one records in Process instance related to this object. i'm not able to delete the record from processinstance object also.

please advise. Thanks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to delete any records that have been in the approval process and remove them from the recycle bin. Then deactivate the approval process. The you may be able to delete it. At one point you could not ever delete it IIRC but the current docs are unclear and seem to indicate it is possible.:

> Active approval processes can't be deleted. Before deleting an approval process, make sure it is inactive and that no records have been submitted for approval. If any records have been submitted, delete them and remove them from the Recycle Bin.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_considerations.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I have tried deactivating them, deleting all records associated to it and even removed from recycle bin and I still can't delete it. Still getting this error http://prntscr.com/kzf50y

Comment: I have been able to delete previously used approval processes by deactivating, deleting all records in that object, and removing from recycle bin.